# Show that the distance $D_c$ between densities is symmetric when the densities are related by a linear transformation

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

The distance between two density functions $p_0$ and $p_1$ is given by

$$D_c(p_0,p_1)=\int_{p_0/p_1>c} (p_0-c p_1)\mathrm{d}\mu$$

where $c>1$ is a real number

> **Question:** Show that if $p_1(y-v)=p_0(-y-u)$ for some real numbers $u$ and $v$, then $D_c(p_0,p_1)=D_c(p_1,p_0)$ for all $c>1$.

**What I can do:**

For $u=v=0$, if I didn't make any mistake I can show this. Actually the problem (in general $u\neq v$) simplifies to showing that

$$\int_{p_0/p_1>c}p_0\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{p_1/p_0>c}p_1\mathrm{d}\mu\quad \mbox{and}\quad \int_{p_0/p_1>c}p_1\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{p_1/p_0>c}p_0\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Since both equations are dual of each other I can consider the first one. Taking $u=v=0$, I have $$l(y)=p_1(y)/p_0(y)=p_0(-y)/p_1(-y)=1/l(-y)$$
Using this

$$\int_{p_0(y)/p_1(y)>c}p_0(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)=\int_{1/c>l(y)}p_0(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)=\int_{1/c>1/l(-y)}p_0(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)=$$ $$\int_{\{y:\,l(-y)>c\}}p_0(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)=\int_{\{-y:\,l(y)>c\}}p_1(-y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)=\int_{\{y:\,l(y)>c\}}p_1(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)$$

**What I couldn't do:**

If $u\neq v$ the same must happen as long as $c>1$ but how to show it, I couldnt do it.

Answer (score 2):

The [layer cake representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) gives another formula for $D_c$:

$$D_c(p_0,p_1)=\int_{p_0/p_1>c} (p_0-c p_1)\mathrm{d}\mu
= \int_0^\infty \mu(\{ p_0-c p_1>t \}) \,dt$$
Thus, it suffices to show that for every $t>0$ the sets $\{ p_0-c p_1>t \}$ and $\{ p_1-c p_0>t \}$ have equal measure.

All that really matters is that $p_1=p_0\circ T$, where $T$ is a measure-preserving *involution*; that is, a measure-preserving bijection such that $T=T^{-1}$. In your case, $Tx=-x-u-v$.

Indeed, since $p_1=p_0\circ T$ and $T$ is an involution, we have $p_0=p_1\circ T$, and therefore
$$\{ p_0-c p_1>t \}= T(\{ p_1-c p_0>t \})$$ 
which implies that the sets have equal measure.

Comment: I have the first and the last question. I am still in need to show that $\{p_0(y):p_1/p_0(y)>c\}\equiv \{p_1(y):p_0/p_1(y)>c\}\forall y$ and $\{p_1(y):p_1/p_0(y)>c\}\equiv \{p_0(y):p_0/p_1(y)>c\}\forall y$. Would it be possible to deduce this as well from your answer?